# How can I define three states boolean but not Nullable?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I have page X for search user data. This page can search for Active, Inactive and all user. When I send active condition to server, I use `bool?` (true = search active user, false = search inactive user, null = search all user) but there is a rule in my company that not allow send `Nullable` value between client and server.

I want to know are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: 3 state boolean brings so many TheDailyWTF memories back. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using a Boolean, I'd use an `enum` as such:

```
 enum SearchOption { Active, Inactive, All }
```

Comment: Also an enum could be communicated as integer or a string (parsed back to enum with `Enum.Parse`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
enum Status { Active, Inactive, All };
```

Edit: Late on this, the link is there to the docs anyway. :) Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

Really the same as they all mentioned, but in-case you not familiar with enums, a few quick examples.

```
enum seachType { activeUsers, inactiveUsers, allUsers }

void doStuff()
{
     // set the the value
     seachType nextSearch = seachType.activeUsers;
     // Conditional statement
     if (nextSearch == seachType.allUsers)
     {
        doMoreStuff();
     }
}
```